# How do I add an id to a konvajs node?

Tags: konvajs

I'm creating a set of circles and would like to iterate through them and highlight based on an identifier of some kind.

It would great if I could just set circle.id = 1, circle.id = 2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create circle
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
  radius: 40,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5
});

// set id
circle.id('foo');

// get id
var name = circle.id();
```

Note: id = type String, inherited from [Konva.Node#id](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#id)

Link: 
https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Circle.html#id__anchor